# Comparative retention rate in various European countries?

Tags: taxes

I am an experienced software developer, currently on GBP £55/hour and have, for several decades, been able to pick & choose where I work.

I am considering returning to Germany, Holland, Switzerland, Belgium, Denmark, maybe others, but tax rates have moved on since I was last there.

I am looking at rates from Eur 85 to 95/hour and expect to work 50 weeks @ 40 hours, so gross of Eur 170k - 190k  .

My only expense is likely to be rent, although my partner, in the same  circumstances, will fly to the UK every two weeks and pay for long term airport parking while overseas.

Can anyone give me an idea of retention in those countries (and others)? No shady schemes, just rendering unto Caesar.

I would be happy enough with a URL for a web site, if that is on topic here, and would return here and post what I discover.

Comment: If your company is British, will you not be taxed in Britain? (at least pre-Brexit)

Comment: Not if resident in Germany for more than 93 days in any given year